# rails aborted! Don't know how to build task 'stimulus_reflex:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, stimulus-reflex

`bundle exec rails stimulus_reflex:install`

gave me this error,
**rails aborted! Don't know how to build task 'stimulus_reflex:install'**

why?

(Commands in sequence...

1. `rails new --skip-spring --webpack=stimulus chatter`
2. `yarn add redis cable_ready stimulus_reflex`
3. `bundle exec rails stimulus_reflex:install`

**rails aborted! Don't know how to build task 'stimulus_reflex:install'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stimulus Reflex has a server and a client part. With yarn you only add the client part.  You need to install `stimulus_reflex` by adding it to your `Gemfile` or running `bundle add stimulus_reflex`

The docs explain how to set it up nicely: https://docs.stimulusreflex.com/setup